# Postgres Docker importing SQL dump on docker build

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, continuous-integration, devops

I'm trying to get rid of Docker-In-Docker, therefore I'm replacing our Postgres images with new ones. For a use case we use a pre-filled Postgres image. The old workflow is to build the image, pull it in a pipeline and use Docker-In-Docker to fill it with data, then re-upload it to the Image registry again.

The new approach is to create the Postgres image with docker, and I've copied the `.sql` Dumps to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. But this fills the image after the startup, I'd like to have a pre-filled image in the container registry because the filling takes up to 2 minutes.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11.12

LABEL maintainer="Hello Stackoverflow"

ARG POSTGRES_VERSION="11.12"
ARG TZ="Europe/Berlin"

ENV TZ ${TZ}
ENV LANG de_DE.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE de_DE.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL de_DE.UTF-8
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD 'blabla'
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD trust

RUN set -x && \
    localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8


COPY test-data/. /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

CMD ["postgres"]
```

In the `test-data`folder is a shell-script which executes the filling

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
echo "read one.sql"
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres  < sql/one.sql
echo "read two.sql"
...
...
...
```

So the idea is to pre-fill the Postgres docker image with the schema and upload to the registry.

Comment: I believe you will need far less acrobatics, if you have a standard postgres image, and another docker with the data that connects to it and loads it with whatever data you need. Separate concerns.

Comment: You could also back up and restore the data directory, either in a named volume or a host directory, rather than trying to transport data in an image.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can rung postgres engine during docker build and execute whatever you need, here is not completely working example, i.e. postgres fails to start because there no configuration file.

if you spend more time on this i bet it should do the trick.

between your lines `COPY test-data/. /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and `CMD ["postgres"]` insert this

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" dbuser
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN echo "dbuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/dbuser && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/dbuser

USER dbuser:dbuser

RUN sudo chown -R dbuser:dbuser /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN sudo chown -R dbuser:dbuser /var/lib/postgresql/

RUN postgres

WORKDIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

RUN psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres  < sql/one.sql
```

at the moment that fails on `RUN postgres` - fails to find configuration **on german**, and i am not expert on postgres neither speak german so i wasn't able to solve right away.

also this part installs sudo and adds new `dbuser` into sudo group because postgress didn't want to start from root, so postgres runs from dbuser.

Hope this is going to help you moving into right direction :)

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work even with ENG. I get the message `postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory`
Any ideas? Seems like the files are not there yet, maybe after first boot

Comment: postgres have no idea if that is docker build or docker container is running. it just cant be aware of current stage, thus it should be totally possible to run it during build. There should be somewhere postgres init command or something like that.